# Software Testing for Data Science in R

Tags: r, software-development

I often use [Nose, Tox or Unittest](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/tests/) when testing my python code, specially when it has to be integrated with other modules or other pieces of code. However, now that I've found myself using R more than python for ML modelling and development. I realized that I don't really test my R code (And more importantly I really don't know how to do it well). So my question is, what are good packages that allow you to test R code in a similar manner as Nose, Tox or Unittest do in Python. Additional references such as tutorials will be greatly appreciated as well.

Bonus points for packages in R similar to

1. [Hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

   or
2. [Feature Forge](https://feature-forge.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

**Related Talk:**

[Trey Causey: Testing for Data Scientists](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GEqM9uJi64Q)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Packages for unit testing and assertive testing that are actively maintained:
Packages for unit testing

1. testthat: more information on how to use you can find [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html) or on [github](https://github.com/hadley/testthat)
2. Runit: [Cran page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RUnit/index.html)

Packages for assertions:

1. assertthat: info on [github](https://github.com/hadley/assertthat)
2. assertive: Assertive has a lot of subpackages available in case you do not need all of them. check on cran
3. assertr: info on [github](https://github.com/tonyfischetti/assertr)
4. ensurer: info on [github](https://github.com/smbache/ensurer)
5. tester: info on [github](https://github.com/gastonstat/tester)

It is a matter of preference what you want to use for assertions. 
Read [this bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org/developers/unitTesting-guidelines/) page for more info on the difference between RUnit and testthat.

Comment: False. RUnit has a new maintainer.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, adjusted based on your info. tnx

Answer (score 1):

For a testing package similar to Hypothesis and based on Haskell's quickcheck, there's the R package from Revolution Analytics called [quickcheck](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/quickcheck).

Comment: it looks great, I will try it out.